# Affordable real-time stereo reconstruction software?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Here's more information:

- I’m interested in capturing the real-time deformation of a small object on the centimeter scale.
- My price limit is $USD 500.00
- The OS I'm using is OS X El Capitan.
- ideally open-source

So far I've come across [reconstructme](http://reconstructme.net/reconstructme-ui/#features) but I'm new to the field of stereo reconstruction so I thought I'd ask for different perspectives.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's owl is another man's nightingale.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations: What features must it have? What's your price limit? On which OS must it run? See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Comment: I just clarified my question. Is this clear enough?

Comment: Definitely better. Whether it's "enough" I cannot tell. To be honest, I still don't have the slightest idea what you're talking about *from your question text* – which might be because it's not my area of proficience. I get a raw idea only after following the link to the example software. As not everybody will follow links to other sites just to find out what is asked for, it *might* help to clearly state the features you want (and what this thing does at all – first association with "stereo" is "sound", which got me quite confused ;).